# Trying to install python package epydoc. Package shows up in help() but not in python itself

Tags: python, epydoc

I tried installing epydoc on mac OSX10.10.

I did so by running

```
'sudo python setup.py install'
```

from the epydoc folder as specified in the readme. 
This seems to install the files correctly 
The weird thing is that when I fire up python and try

```
epydoc -help
```

It does not find epydoc but when I enter help() and than epydoc it does work which seems to me that it is installed but my python somehow cannot find it.

Does anyone know how I can get this package to run

Comment: That is not the proper syntax for Python. You would write `epydoc -help` on the terminal, but not in a Python shell. In Python, you need to `import` the package. Please Google/look at the docs for your package since I'm not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: Ok thank you, that was clearly quite a stupid mistake. Thanks that helped me out